# How to differentiate if user zoomed in or zoomed out on view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

How to differentiate if user zoomed in or zoomed out on a view?

Is there any direct property/method available to detect the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` then you can do that using `gestureRecognizer.velocity` property.

Value of velocity is negative when current scale is smaller then previous and positive when it scale increases.